# Read parameters and stdin to same variable, keeping space

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to write a program which processes files given as input to the program, but I want to support both piping in values as well as sending them in via parameters.

For example, one might want to run the program on all files in the current directory with the flags -dvs:

```
find . -type f | program -dvs
```

or maybe you want to do the same, but for all the files in the $FILES_TO_CHECK variable:

```
echo "$FILES_TO_CHECK" | program -dvs
```

This is the code I have so far:

```
tmp1() {
  local in=("$@")

  if read -t 0 -u 0; then
    local pipe=""
    read -d '' -u 0 pipe
    in+=(${pipe})
  fi

  local param
  for param in "${!in[@]}"; do
    echo "'$param' => '${in[$param]}'"
  done
}
```

with the test:

```
echo "cba" "bca" "cba abc" | tmp1 "a" "b" "c" "abc" "abc cba"
echo; echo; echo
find . -type f
find . -type f | tmp1 "a" "b" "c" "abc" "abc cba"
```

The above gives the following output:

```
'0' => 'a'
'1' => 'b'
'2' => 'c'
'3' => 'abc'
'4' => 'abc cba'
'5' => 'cba'
'6' => 'bca'
'7' => 'cba'
'8' => 'abc'



./1
./2
./3
'0' => 'a'
'1' => 'b'
'2' => 'c'
'3' => 'abc'
'4' => 'abc cba'
```

Which is close, but not exactly what I want:

```
'0' => 'a'
'1' => 'b'
'2' => 'c'
'3' => 'abc'
'4' => 'abc cba'
'5' => 'cba'
'6' => 'bca'
'7' => 'cba abc'



./1
./2
./3
'0' => 'a'
'1' => 'b'
'2' => 'c'
'3' => 'abc'
'4' => 'abc cba'
'5' => './1'
'6' => './2'
'7' => './3'
```

I'm not sure the top case (maintaining space characters from piped values) is possible at all, but if it is, how would you go about it?
As for the second case, why doesn't the output from find ever get read by the program?

EDIT: If there is any other, better way to do this I'm all ears as well.
The actual loop will later on be far more complex, so I would want to avoid making one loop for parameters and another for piped values.

Comment: Using `read -t 0` to conditionally read from stdin is an anti-pattern. UNIX commands ought to be predictable: either always read from stdin, or never do it. I'd advise keeping it simple and only parse the command-line. The user can use `xargs` if they want to convert output into arguments.

Comment: If I attempt to use `xargs` I get the output `xargs: tmp1: No such file or directory`. If I could get this working I'd agree with you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `tmp` is reading null-delimited records from standard input, but your test is sending whitespace-separate strings. Test with

```
printf '%s\0' "cba" "bca" "cba abc" | tmp1 "a" "b" "c" "abc" "abc cba"
find . -type f -print0 | tmp1 ...
```

(This assumes a version of `find` that can output null-terminated file names.)

Inside `tmp`, you need to loop over the input to get each file, then quote `$pipe` as well when adding it to the array

```
if read -t 0 -u 0; then
  local pipe=""
  while read -d '' pipe; do
    in+=("$pipe")
  done
fi
```

If you are using `bash` 4.4 or later, you can use `readarray` instead of a loop.

```
readarray -t -d '' -O "${#in[@]}" in
```

Comment: I suppose I could change the if statement to a while loop, change the delimeter to a newline and ask users to separate by that instead...  

I was hoping for some magical solution that kept the data of whether or not the whitespaces were part of the input flag after piping, but I suppose that won't be possible.  

Do you have any idea on the find-issue?

Comment: The null character is the only safe option for separating file names, because it's the only character that can't appear in a file name.

Comment: What if `find` doesn't output anything right away? The `read -t 0` is quite fragile.

Comment: @chepner good point, and I suppose you can always use `echo -e "abc\0 abc cba\0"` if you're really desperate. And in response to the edits about find, I think the (current) issue lies more with what @John Kugelman is talking about (although the -print0 flag will most likely help afterwards)